# Inserting test data which references another table without hard coding the foreign key values

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite

I'm trying to write a SQL query that will insert test data into two tables, one of which references the other.

Tables are created from something like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE address (
  address_id INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  ...[irrelevant columns]
);

CREATE TABLE member (
  ...[irrelevant columns],
  address INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY(address) REFERENCES address(address_id)
);
```

I want ids in both tables to auto increment, so that I can easily insert new rows later without having to look into the table for ids.

I need to insert some test data into both tables, about 25 rows in each. Hardcoding ids for the insert causes issues with inserting new rows later, as the automatic values for the id columns try and start with 1 (which is already in the database). So I need to let the ids be automatically generated, but I also need to know which ids are in the database for inserting test data into the member database - I don't believe the autogenerated ones are guaranteed to be consecutive, so can't assume I can safely hardcode those.

This is test data - I don't care which record I link each member row I am inserting to, only that there is an address record in the address table with that id.

My thoughts for how to do this so far include:

1. Insert addresses individually, returning the id, then use that to insert an individual member (cons: potentially messy, not sure of the syntax, harder to see expected sets of addresses/members in the test data)
2. Do the member insert with a `SELECT address_id FROM address WHERE [some condition that will only give one row]` for the address column (cons: also a bit messy, involves a quite long statement for something I don't care about)

**Is there a neater way around this problem?**

I particularly wonder if there is a way to either:

- Let the auto increment controlling functions be aware of manually inserted id values, or
- Get the list of inserted ids from the address table into a variable which I can use values from in turn to insert members.

Ideally, I'd like this to work with as many (irritatingly slightly different) database engines as possible, but I need to support at least postgresql and sqlite - ideally in a single query, although I could have two separate ones. (I have separate ones for creating the tables, the sole difference being `INTEGER GENEREATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY` instead of just `IDENTITY`.)

Comment: Yes, there is a way, using a *chained* set of CTEs.

Comment: What language are you accessing the DBs from?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-sequence.html

Sounds like `LASTVAL()` is what you're looking for.  It was also work in the real world to maintain transactional consistency between multiple selects, as it's scoped to your sessions last insert.